# Passing multiple arguments to running console application from windows form

Tags: c#, .net, process, ipc

I have the console application, lets name it **X.exe**. It works with two arguments lets say 'a' and 'a.tmp' where **a** *is my input file name* and **a.tmp** *is output filename*. On console I usually run application like: **X a a.tmp** 
*but first I have to be present in location of input file 'a' else application wont work if I tried to give its absolute path.*
I have created windows form to run these console application, but as I said earlier application must be started in file location.
I tried using process object but application was not working.
I created two processes:

1. *go to the file location*
2. *to execute application on file
       location*

**`Question:  can I excute these multiple commands in one go and avoid using IPC?`**

Comment: You can also provide the absolute (full path) to your files.

Comment: 2 processes will not help. One process will change the current working directory, whereas the other will not. Two processes are just that: two processes doing their own thing independently of another. Just in case your X.exe does not support full absolute paths for its arguments, a solution can easily be found by looking into the documentation for `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` and `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can use is the `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.

E.g. from [MS Docs - ProcessStartInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The `WorkingDirectory` property behaves differently when `UseShellExecute` is `true` than when `UseShellExecute` is `false`. When `UseShellExecute` is `true`, the `WorkingDirectory` property specifies the location of the executable. If `WorkingDirectory` is an empty string, the current directory is understood to contain the executable.
>
> *Note - When `UseShellExecute` is `true`, the working directory of the application that starts the executable is also the working directory of the executable.*
>
> When `UseShellExecute` is `false`, the `WorkingDirectory` property is not used to find the executable. Instead, its value applies to the process that is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

E.g.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {                
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "X.exe"; /
            myProcess.WorkingDirectory = "C:\SomeDirectory That contains A and A.tmp"
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: X.exe is excutable everywhere but input parameter cant be absolute path.And that's why I first need to present at file location.And suppose if my drive is other than default c:\ ,it wont change to specified location.

Comment: then you just set the working directory to the path where `A` and `A.exe` exist